# How to get file path in node js and pass to the DB request

Tags: html, node.js, postgresql, file, express

I use Node.js express + PostgreSQL

How to pass the path to my CSV file through Node.js in a BD query ?

I have and html form which is having file input like -

```
<form method="post" action="import_csv" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<p><input type="file" name="csv_file">
<input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
</form>
```

After, I have redirected this post request to the following method of controller (server).

```
app.post("/import_csv_file",urlencodedParser,function(req,res) {

    var config = {
        user:'postgres',
        database:'mybd',
        password: '1',
        host:'localhost',
        port:5432,
        max:10,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    }
    var pool = new pg.Pool(config)
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
        console.log("teacher")
        if(err){
            return console.error('error')
        }
        file_path = req.body.csv_file
        console.log(file_path)


        client.query("select * from import_csv($1,$2)",[log2,req.body.csv_file], function(err, result) {
            done()
        req.session.user2 = result
        if (err){
            res.end()
            return console.error("error")
       }
        res.render('import_csv_file',{jour:result}})
      })
       })
```

The result I am getting here is -  undefined   (console.log(req.body.csv_file))

How do I pass the path to my CSV file to a database query so that everything works

Comment: Try console logging req.body first

Comment: @Syntle I don't understand what do you mean. `file_path = req.body.csv_file
        console.log(file_path)`. log gives me the result - undefined

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `urlencodedParser` don't match

Comment: @Quentin I started to see the file name. But how to pass the path so that the DB query understands where to get the file?  `file_path = req.body.csv_file console.log(file_path)` result - db.csv 
I deleted - `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: You can't. File inputs upload *files*. It doesn't help the server to know where the file is on the visitor's computer. It can't read the visitor's hard disk. If it could there would be no privacy in the world.

Comment: @JuniorLittle console.log(req.body)

Comment: @Quentin If it's on my localhost ? And how then to pass my file to the request?

Comment: @Syntle when I used `enctype="multipart/form-data"` Result = Object { }. But when I did not use. Result = Object {csv_file: "bd2.csv"}

Comment: @JuniorLittle — See my first comment.

Comment: @Quentin I removed `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. and now see the file name, but the DB query does not understand. Such as - db.csv. 
He needs a path, as I understand it

Comment: You need multipart in order to send the file.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, I'm a little confused. What can I do then ?

Comment: @JuniorLittle — Use a body parser that supports multipart requests.

Comment: @Quentin You don't have a random example ?

Comment: @Quentin I did it, I used - multer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help !

installer multer and next

```
    const path = require('path')
    var multer = require('multer');
    const upload = multer({ dest: '/tmp/' });

    app.post("/import_csv_file",upload.any(),function(req,res) {

        var config = {
            user:'postgres',
            database:'mybd',
            password: '1',
            host:'localhost',
            port:5432,
            max:10,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
        }
        var pool = new pg.Pool(config)
        pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
            console.log("teacher")
            if(err){
                return console.error('error')
            }
           console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.files);

  const file = req.files[0];
 console.log(file)
 console.log(file.path)


            client.query("select * from import_csv($1,$2)",[log2,file.path], function(err, result) {
                done()
            req.session.user2 = result
            if (err){
                res.end()
                return console.error("error")
           }
            res.render('import_csv_file',{jour:result}})
          })
           })
```

and html

```
<form method="post" action="inside_teacher_import_ocenka" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><input type="file" name="csv_ocenka">
<input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```